# How to create drag-and-drop installer for MacOS X?

Tags: macos, installation, osx-snow-leopard

What tools are used to create installers like this:

[image]

EDIT:
Here's a full tutorial: http://chromasoft.blogspot.com/2010/02/building-dmg-installer-for-mac-simple.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just a folder with a custom background image (right click on the folder background and select "Show View Options"; Firefox also sets a larger icon size and adjusts the grid to match, also in the same place).  The link to `/Applications` is created by <kbd>Control</kbd>-dragging.  Once you have the original folder set up, you can use [`hdiutil`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/hdiutil.1.html) to create a DMG disk image from the folder.

Comment: Or Disk Utility, to do it interactively.

Answer (score 1):

goin to **Disk Utility**

```
File>New Image>Blank Image
```

- Select the Settings (Size must be lager than files you want to store)
- Open DMG to mount the image
- Drag into the folder of image your App, and an Applications Folder Alias.
- Right-Click on image folder>Show View Options .

And then you can customize your background, etc.